# I have an onscreen keyboard built in WPF, having trouble detecting physical button presses

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there any way to make my onscreen button appear pressed when my physical button is also pressed? I can not find a solution that works that works across the board.

I've tried using eventhandler but it doesn't work with every button.

Comment: I'd create a KeyViewModel with an IsPressed property. Then I'd create a KeyboardViewModel with a each key as a KeyViewModel property. Finally, in the Window or UserControl's KeyDown and KeyUp event handlers, I'd set the appropriate KeyViewModel property's IsPressed to True/False respectively.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Hmm, then the View is responsible for mouse input (click on a Button) and the ViewModel for keyboard input. Sounds strange to me. IMHO the View is responsible for the whole UI which includes visualization and interaction.

Comment: @Theod12344: What exactly have you tried? What doesn't work?